# Is there a better way to rearrange this array?

Tags: php, arrays, function, variables

is there a better (more efficient way) to make the first and last key's to swap places in this array??

```
 <?php 

 function jim_is_jill($user_names) {
    $user_A = $user_names[0];
    $user_B = $user_names[1];
    $user_C = $user_names[2];
    $user_D = $user_names[3];

    $new_arr = array($user_D, $user_B, $user_C, $user_A);

    return $new_arr;

 }

 $user_names = array('Jim', 'Josh', 'Jamie', 'Jill');
 print_r(jim_is_jill($user_names));
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
list($user_names[0],$user_names[3]) = array($user_names[3],$user_names[0]);
```

In general:

```
list($a,$b) = array($b,$a);
```

This is the best way to swap two variables without using any temporary vars.

You can also make a function to swap arbitrary entries:

```
function swap(&$arr,$x,$y) {
    list($arr[$x],$arr[$y]) = array($arr[$y],$arr[$y]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about just swapping them like this:

```
...
$temp = $user_names[0];
$user_names[0] = $user_names[3];
$user_names[3] = $temp;
...
```

Comment: Good god... You're wonderful. How did you learn PHP? (If you don't mind me asking?)

Comment: Glad to help :) mainly at school and working with web security.